# How do I create a static class using DOJO in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dojo, static-classes

I am trying to create a Utility class in JavaScript and am using the Dojo framework. I can't find anywhere on here about how to properly create a static class within the Dojo framework. I don't want to have to create a new Utility object every time. I would prefer not to use a Singleton either.

I currently have something like this...

```
//Util.js

define(["dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/domReady!"], function (declare) {
        return declare(null, {
            //Pass in string format of element's ID
            clearTextBox: function (elemID) {
                document.getElementById(elemID).value = "";
            }
        });
    });
```

NOTE: I am using AMD not Legacy code

Comment: What don't you like about using a singleton?

Comment: I would like to use this class similar to java.util.Math in which it can be called in many different contexts easily. I am also not storing any states and would like the benefit of its performance/memory over a singleton. All of the methods used in this class will be static as well. For all intents and purposes of this class, it makes more sense to use a static class rather than a singleton. I'm not strictly against singletons, I would just like it to be a static class in this case.

Comment: What about doing something like this? http://www.benlesh.com/2012/05/javascript-fun-part-3-implementing.html

Comment: Due to using the Dojo Toolkit, I can't really create one that way (from what I have tried so far). The implementation I have used in the above example is what I am stuck to. This is why I am looking for a way to create a static class with Dojo. Just not sure how yet...

Comment: What is wrong with what you have? Notice that there are no classes in JS, and no "static" ones either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As alluded to in one of the comments, you don't need a "class" at all to do what you are asking.  This is JavaScript, not Java or C# or etc.

You just need to define a module which returns an object with utility functions.

```
define([], function () {
    return {
        clearTextBox: function (id) {
            document.getElementById(id).value = '';
        }
    };
});
```

This is a very common practice, even employed by Dojo itself for utility modules such as `dojo/_base/array`, `dojo/_base/lang`, and `dojo/date`.

This also does not create a new object each time, as each AMD module is only ever loaded once, and its factory function is only ever executed once.

Dojo is a toolkit, not a framework, and generally never forces you to do something a certain way.  Don't get trapped into thinking that every module you ever create needs to be a "class" using `declare`.  Use `declare` when you need to define a constructor or mixin with inheritance capabilities.